# Visualization of ASes, prefix and the Internet backbone

Tags: internet, bgp, visualization

Last year, I had found a site that had an application (either Java or Flash, I can't remember) that displayed an interactive graph of the ASes in the backbone of the Internet. You could select any AS and see in graph form which were its peers, along with a lot of other information, including the announcements received in the last 2-3 days.

For every AS, you could get its whois information, and the prefixes that it was announcing. Everything was interactive.

It was a fantastic visualization and demonstration tool that I showed to my students (Computer Networks course), in order for them to have a glance at how the Internet looks like in its core, how BGP routing was working to keep our packets flowing, etc.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find this link anymore, and I would like to show it again this year to my students. I would like to know any information about this site, or any other sites that provide good interactive and interesting visualizations about the inner workings of the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find [BGPlay](http://bgplay.routeviews.org/) to be interesting and useful.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the tool that I originally was looking for:

- [Routing Information Service (RIS)](http://www.ripe.net/ris/)